# How can I play different videos for each different SeassionCard in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-video-player

I want to play videos in each SeassionCards. Should I create different dart file for each video? Or, Is there a chance to bring videos by one by for every single buttons?

[image: U/I and code]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have something like this in your code

```
...
children:[
SessionCard(
    sessionNum:1,
    press:(){ }
),
SessionCard(
    sessionNum:2,
    press:(){ }
),
SessionCard(
    sessionNum:3,
    press:(){ }
),
SessionCard(
    sessionNum:4,
    press:(){ }
),
]
```

change it to this

you can store your data in a list

//create a class

```
class SessionCardMode{
final int sessionNum;
final String videoUrl;

SessionCardModel(this.sessionNum, this.videoUrl);
}
```

in the top  of your widget fill in your data

```
final List<SessionCardModel> sessionItems = 
[
SessionCardModel(1, 'https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4?_=1'),
SessionCardModel(2, 'https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4?_=1'),
SessionCardModel(3, 'https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4?_=1'),
SessionCardModel(4, 'https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4?_=1'),
SessionCardModel(5, 'https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4?_=1'),
SessionCardModel(6, 'https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4?_=1'),
]
```

and in your list, change it something like this

```
...
children:List.generate(sessionItems.length,(index) => 
SessionCard(
    sessionNum:sessionItems[index].sessionNum,
    press:(){
        // you can get the videoUrl of the particular session
        // by using sessionItems[index].videoUrl
        // you can open the video here 
     }
));
```

this will clean up the code a little and solve your proplem